# ZF2 Literal Routes are not being matched

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I am trying to set up Zend Framework 2 with multiple site specific modules. Each module configuration includes its own uniquely named literal path route. However, these routes are always ignored in favor of the "home" route in the application module. The URL points to the physical location of the index.php file for ZF2.

So, URL: localhost/zend/module/name/public/

config:

```
'routes' => array(
        'moduleByPath' => array(
            'type' => 'Literal',
            'options' => array(
                'route' => '/zend/module/name/public/'
            ),
            'may_terminate' => true,
            'child_routes' => $childRoutes,
        ),
    ),
```

But, I get matched to "home" as defined in the default Application. If I change the home route from '/' to '/doesntexist/' I get an error that the path doesn't match routing.

The module is being included correctly, as I can add a route to match by domain and everything loads correctly.

Comment: Are you saying that /zend/module/name/public/ is a physical directory?

Comment: It is, yes. That is where the index.php file is located.

Answer (score 0):

ZF2 'Literal' routes do not match up to physical directories, it just means a literal URI, rather than a 'Segment' URI for example that can take parameters like :action or :controller etc.

To make that route work in the example, you would need to move index.php up to the root /, ensure .htaccess is working correctly and remove the 'zend' physical directory and all subdirectories completely.

This will then cause ZF2 to map the literal URI /zend/module/name/public/ to that route 'moduleByPath', and process child_routes where necessary.

Also, normally for Literal routes you would declare a default controller and action that should load for this URI like this:

```
<?php
return [
    'routes' => [
        'api' => [
            'type' => 'Literal',
            'options' => [
                'route' => '/api',
                'defaults' => [
                    'controller' => 'api',
                    'action' => 'index',
                ],
            ],
            'may_terminate' => true,
            'child_routes' => [
                // ...
            ]
        ]
    ]
 ];
```

For example. Ensuring you have the controller 'api' declared as invokeable in the config too:

```
<?php
// ...
'controllers' => [
    'invokables' => [
        'api'        => 'MoudleName\Controller\ApiController'
        // ... other invokables
    ]
]
```

Hope this helps, let me know if i'm not making sense :) Happy coding